# Why isnt the sound playing, no errors in the code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

The sound clip is 4 seconds, wav file and 700kb in size.

Here is the code which I have used, I have linked everything up included the framework of AVAudioPlayer etc.

```
- (IBAction)twoSound:(id)sender; {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2b" ofType:@"wav"];
    if (theAudio) [theAudio release];
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];   

}
```

When I tap the button it makes a small "bump" noise, but this isn't the noise it's supposed to do.

Thanks

Comment: You should start by capturing the error of the AVAudioPlayer initialization. That's why it's there.

Comment: Are you sure you've got the right resource path? Is it `2b` or not `2b`? ;-)

Comment: Lol - Yeah the file name is 2b.wav so the source is correct, this is so weird - On another view it works,  but on this view it doesnt! Gr

Comment: So, two usages, two different sound files. One usage works, one doesn't. Call me crazy but it I would guess it is the sound file. Try the sound file that works in the usage that doesn't to close in on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use AAC or CAF instead; [Preferred Audio Formats in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW33)

Comment: I have 2 view controllers
One view controller full of sounds which work
2nd view controller doesnt work, and thats the same code but different file sound name